# Hung IIS requests RequestAcquireState

Tags: iis, aspstate

From time to time we are running into an issue where we have many requests with the following state in IIS: `RequestAcquireState`.

We are using `SqlSessionStateStore` to manage sessions.  When we have many requests in this state they eventually time out and go away.  Sometimes they are there for over an hour.

What I do see when we have these hung sessions is an increase in the executions of the stored procedure `TempGetStateItemExclusive3` in the ASPState database.  Up to 2,000 every few seconds.  Not good.

I was hoping someone could help me with the following questions:

1. How do these sessions hang
2. Do they cause any harm other than the increased db activity
3. Is it possible to kill the individual requests safely
4. Many people suggest a restart of the AppPool this is not good for people currently using the system
5. Is there a way of identifying these sessions in the ASPState database and what happens if you delete them

Comment: sorry what do you mean by "share edit delete flag"?

Comment: Pretty please does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The hang is caused by the underlying framework not triggering EndRequest as explained in this [KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2828841).

You haven't included which version of IIS/.NET you are running so the HotFix in the article may be applicable to you.

Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to have been fixed properly in later versions of .NET and I am still having the same problem which I have also [asked about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39389182/requestacquirestate-hanging-on-net-4-5-1-iis8).